# Android Sliding Drawer with first row always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I've created an Android sliding drawer but when it is dismissed it is completely hidden. The behavior that I'm looking for is to have the first row of the drawer visible at all times. If this is possible what is the best way to attempt this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1a"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionsSlider = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
    actionsSlider.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
            firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            firstButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    actionsSlider.setOnDrawerScrollListener(new OnDrawerScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStarted() {
            if (!actionsSlider.isOpened()) {
                findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1a);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollEnded() {
        }
    });
}
```